# Where to place JOptionPaneShowInputDialog code?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Where to place JOptionPaneShowInputDialog code?
Where to place JOptionPaneShowInputDialog code?Where to place JOptionPaneShowInputDialog code?
Where to place JOptionPaneShowInputDialog code?
Where to place JOptionPaneShowInputDialog code?
I would like to add a JoptionPaneShowInputDialog()(not in code yet) inside the code herebelow.

I can do, but I cannot make the dialog appearing in the black panel,before the recursion.

The dialog appears after the drawing...

```
public class FractalTree extends JPanel implements ActionListener
     {

      int x1=350;  
      int y1=600;
      int angle=-90;
      int depth=11;          
      int k=10;

      JLabel label_1;

      private void drawTree(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, double angle, int depth, int k)
         {
          if(depth==11)

          g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
          g.fillRect(100, 600, 1160, 10);
          g.setColor(Color.white);
          if (depth == 0) return;

          ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke((float) (k*0.9)));
          int x2 = x1 + (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 11*Math.random()+1);
          int y2 = y1 + (int) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 11*Math.random()+1);
          if(depth<3)
           {
             g.setColor(Color.green);
           }

          g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
          drawTree(g, x2, y2, angle - 19, depth-1,k-1);
          drawTree(g, x2, y2, angle + 19, depth-1,k-1);

         }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {       
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);

            drawTree(g,x1,y1,angle,depth,k);
            drawTree(g,x1+600,y1,angle,depth,k);    
     }


    public FractalTree()
     {      
       this.setBackground(Color.black);  
     }

    public static void gui()
          {
           JFrame f=new JFrame("fractal tree");
           JLabel label_1=new JLabel("<html>RANDOM TREE<br><center>FRACTAL");
           label_1.setForeground(Color.red);
           Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD,25);
           label_1.setFont(font);
           FractalTree ft=new FractalTree();
           f.getContentPane().add(ft);
           f.setSize(1500, 1000);
           JButton button = new JButton("Close Me");
           button.addActionListener(ft);    
           f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);         
           ft.add(label_1);
           ft.add(button);
           f.setUndecorated(true);
           f.setVisible(true);
          }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {               
        gui();      
        }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        System.exit(0);     
        }
}
```

May I ask some help?
Thanks

Comment: You need a flag which can be used in `paintComponent` to stop it from painting the tree when you don't want it to

Comment: Thanks... you mean I need to add some code in the paintComponent method?

Comment: Understand, you don't control the paint process and painting may be done at anytime for any number reasons, also, painting should run as fast as possible.  So, if you want to "stop" the painting from occurring, you need to add a flag which determines when the tree should be painted, this is checked in `paintComponent`, but is set externally.  Don't put `JOptionPane` in `paintComponent`

Comment: Thanks but I'm almost beginner in Java

Comment: ok, thanks, but by" flag" you mean I have to add some code? Sorry, almost beginner...

Comment: Message dialogs and input dialogs are shown in exact points in a program flow? In your case, when do you want to show this input dialog? At the very beginning before you display the panel? Or after you show the panel? What is the input you are trying to get from the user with this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The question and intent are some what unclear.  What is the purpose of the dialog?

I assume you want to gather some information which can then be passed to the `FractalTree` to change it's rendering

The question and intent are some what unclear.  What is the purpose of the dialog?

I assume you want to gather some information which can then be passed to the `FractalTree` to change it's rendering, in that case you probably need to put the dialog before the creation of the `FractalTree`

```
public static void gui()
{
    // You can put the dialog here...
    JFrame f=new JFrame("fractal tree");
    //...
```

If you want to change the properties `FractalTree` after its been displayed, then you probably need to use a `JButton` and a `ActionListener` and place the dialog in there ... or provide a second view to gather the properties directly

> In fact, the purpose of the dialog box is to ask the recursion level. If I place it like you propose, its ok, but the dialog box appears alone, not in the black panel, and I would like that it appears in the panel...

Let's just be clear, SO is NOT a tutorial or mentoring site. Your problem isn't a technical problem, but an experience one. You should spend more time reading through tutorials like [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and trying things.  This is how you will become a better developer and learn to solve your own problems.

Based on your feedback, `JOptionPane` isn't what you need.

Instead, you need to take a slightly different approach and supply your own input component.

First, you need to change `FractalTree` so that you can modify the `depth` property more easily (and set the initial depth to `0` so it will stop drawing)

```
public class FractalTree extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private int depth = 0; // set to 0 to stop it from rendering

    public void setDepth(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }
```

Next, you need to create your own input component, which can take input from the user and update the tree

```
public class InputPane extends JPanel {
    private FractalTree fractalTree;

    private JTextField depthField;

    public InputPane(FractalTree fractalTree) {
        this.fractalTree = fractalTree;
        depthField = new JTextField(10);
        depthField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String text = depthField.getText().trim();
                try {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(text);
                    fractalTree.setDepth(value);
                } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(InputPane.this, text + " is not a valid numerical value");
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Then you want to create a new entry point that can combine the two...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FractalTree tree = new FractalTree();
                InputPane input = new InputPane(tree);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(tree);
                frame.add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Yes, this is going to produce a small window, because `FractalTree` doesn't define any sizing hints, which can be solved by overriding it's `getPreferredSize` method and returning a more suitable size.

This is going to put you own a "better path", there are still issues you're going to have to solve, because doing it all for you won't help you

Comment: In fact, the purpose of the dialog box is to ask the recursion level. If I place it like you propose, its ok, but the dialog box appears alone, not in the black panel, and I would like that it appears in the panel...Thank you. Francis

Comment: @Francis `JOptionPane` won't "appear" in the panel, it will be displayed as a dialog, that's kind of the point.  If you want to provide an additional view, then you're going to have to make a new `JPanel` and add into the existing view - all of which is beyond the scope of SO - as it now makes the question to broad